# Как сделать очистку бота при нажатии на InlineButton?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Создал две таблицы:

В `media_message_table` хранятся id коллекций, фотографий и т.д.;

В `message_table` хранятся id последних сообщений.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

##### Написал четыре метода:

##### 1 Добавляю последнее сообщение:

```
void AddMessage(long _userId, int _messId)
{
    try
    {
        using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(db.conn.ConnectionString))
        {
            db.conn.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand command2 = db.conn.CreateCommand();
            command2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO message_table VALUES (@userId, @messId)";
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", _userId);
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@messId", _messId);
            command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            db.conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
    }
}
```

##### 2 Добавляю id коллекции:

```
void AddMediaGroup(long _userId, int _messId, int _countMess)
{
    try
    {
        using (NpgsqlConnection? connection = new(db.conn.ConnectionString))
        {
            db.conn.Open();
            for (int i = 1; i < _countMess; i++)
            {
                NpgsqlCommand command2 = db.conn.CreateCommand();
                command2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO media_message_table VALUES (@userId, @messId)";
                command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", _userId);
                command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@messId", _messId + i);
                command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            db.conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
    }
}
```

##### 3 Удаляю последнее сообщение:

```
void DeleteMessage()
{
    try
    {
        using (NpgsqlConnection? connection = new(db.conn.ConnectionString))
        {
            db.conn.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand command2 = db.conn.CreateCommand();
            command2.CommandText = "SELECT user_id, message_id FROM message_table";
            NpgsqlDataReader reader = command2.ExecuteReader();
            List<string?[]> data = new();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                data.Add(new string[2]);
                data[^1][0] = reader[0].ToString();
                data[^1][1] = reader[1].ToString();
            }
            reader.Close();
            db.conn.Close();
            foreach (string?[] s in data)
            {
                if (userId.ToString() == s[0]!.ToString())
                {
                    context.Client.DeleteMessageAsync(
                        Convert.ToInt64(s[0]),
                        Convert.ToInt32(s[1]),
                        cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                    try
                    {
                        db.conn.Open();
                        NpgsqlCommand command = db.conn.CreateCommand();
                        command.CommandText = $"DELETE FROM message_table WHERE message_id = {Convert.ToInt32(s[1])}";
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        db.conn.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
    }
}
```

##### 4 Удаляю сообщения коллекции:

```
void DeleteMediaMessage()
{
    try
    {
        using (NpgsqlConnection? connection = new(db.conn.ConnectionString))
        {
            db.conn.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand command2 = db.conn.CreateCommand();
            command2.CommandText = "SELECT user_id, message_id FROM media_message_table WHERE user_id = {userId}";
            NpgsqlDataReader reader = command2.ExecuteReader();
            List<string?[]> data = new();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                data.Add(new string[2]);
                data[^1][0] = reader[0].ToString();
                data[^1][1] = reader[1].ToString();
            }
            reader.Close();
            db.conn.Close();
            foreach (string?[] s in data)
            {
                if (userId == Convert.ToInt64(s[0]))
                {
                    context.Client.DeleteMessageAsync(
                        Convert.ToInt32(s[0]),
                        Convert.ToInt32(s[1]),
                        cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                    try
                    {
                        db.conn.Open();
                        NpgsqlCommand command = db.conn.CreateCommand();
                        command.CommandText = $"DELETE FROM media_message_table WHERE user_id = {userId} AND message_id = {Convert.ToInt32(s[1])}";
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        db.conn.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
        db.conn.Close();
    }
}
```

##### Вот как использую:

```
switch (context.Update?.CallbackQuery?.Data)
{
    case "key_btn1":
        await context.Client.SendMediaGroupAsync(
            context.ChatId,
            media: new IAlbumInputMedia[]
            {
                new InputMediaPhoto("https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/clean-white-fur-background-close-up-view-texture-wallpaper_118047-6999.jpg"),
                new InputMediaPhoto("https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/clean-white-fur-background-close-up-view-texture-wallpaper_118047-6999.jpg"),
                new InputMediaPhoto("https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/clean-white-fur-background-close-up-view-texture-wallpaper_118047-6999.jpg")
            },
            cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        await context.Client.SendTextMessageAsync(
            context.ChatId,
            text:"Текст сообщения............",
            replyMarkup: key.btn2,
            cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        AddMessage(userId, messId); //добавляю последнее сообщение
        AddMediaGroup(userId, messId, 4); //добавляю коллекцию
        break;
    case "key_btn2":
        await context.Client.SendTextMessageAsync(
            context.ChatId,
            text:"Текст сообщения...........",
            replyMarkup: key.btn2,
            cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        AddMessage(userId, messId);
        DeleteMediaMessage(); //если перейти с btn1, то коллекция удалиться
        break;
}
DeleteMessage(); //удаляю последнее сообщение
```

Код рабочий, но есть один `БАГ`:
Если одновременно нажать на одно и то же сообщение двум или более пользователям то коллекции(если они есть) удаляться только у пользователя который первее нажмет на другую кнопку, при чем
удаление коллекций из таблицы `media_message_table` проходит правильно

Comment: И что вам мешает после отправки сообщения, сохранять его id для будущего удаления? У вас вон даже всякие `SendPhotoAsync` отдают сразу объект сообщения, у которого явно есть id. То есть, либо делаете `Task` отправки сообщения, который делает следующее: отправляет, ждет N сек, удаляет. То есть его цель - следить за одним сообщением. Либо делаете коллекцию (наверно лучше очередь), в которую после отправки сообщения отправляете id и после всех действий бота, запускаете циклом удаление.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ,  добавил скрины. Что не так делаю?

Comment: Хм, а мне от куда знать, что вы делаете не так?) Проверяйте все значения, смотрите чтобы id чата и id сообщения были нужными. Пройдитесь пошагово по коду и посмотрите, где вы получаете не то, что надо. Я по скринам (кстати, за код в виде скринов на SO надо ругать!!) например вижу, что `chatId` выделяется, что говорит "оно может быть `NULL`, а значит вы в теории можете передавать API null значения. Далее, почему `update.CallbackQuery.Message.MessageId`? Вы уверены, что данное сообщение хотите удалить? В моем понимании вы хотите удалять сообщения бота, а его id например тут `message1.MessageId`.